# How to ngAnimate views rather than nav bar?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I've created an angularjs app but I'm not sure how to animate the whole page in between transitions.

I have a nav-bar on the top of index.html.  The nav bar already animates when I change between ..home ...about..invest...contact etc.  But How do I animate between views?  Perhaps a slight fade in/fade out etc between view transitions when I've clicked on the nav bar button  ?  I've searched all over online but sadly it's all referring to ngAnimate with ng-click effects?

Thanks.

```
 <body>

<ng-controller = "demoCtrl">

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
        <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
        <a ui-sref="form">Join Us</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('about') }">
        <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('invest') }">
       <a ui-sref="invest">Investments</a>
      </li>

      <li ng-class="{active: isState('contact') }"> </div>
        <a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">          </h3>
    <br>
    <div ui-view="">


</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you are using to animate the navbar?

Comment: you can only animate a view, repeat, include, switch, if and show/hide ... do you want to animate one of those? if yes, please check this examples: http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: Thanks.  I want to animate the ngView but I'm afraid the nganimate website is out of date.